# Web.Config custom section returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config, opayo

Well I have following entries in my web config for SagePay Integration in an ASP.net MVC project.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<section name="SagePayConfiguration" type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" requirePermission="true" restartOnExternalChanges="true" allowLocation="true"/>

</configSections> 

<SagePayConfiguration>
    <!--Mandatory     
    Set to TEST for the Test Server and LIVE for the live environment-->
    <add key="sagepay.api.env" value="TEST" />
    .
    .
</SagePayConfiguration>
```

However I am getting null when trying to access it from C# code.

```
SagePayConfiguration sagePayConfiguration = (SagePayConfiguration)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SagePayConfiguration");
```

Any help what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cast the ConfigrationItem to "System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler" or set the type Attribute in web.conf to an existing Type in your assembly.

`<section name="<SectionName>" type="<your type (FQN)>, <Assembly>" />`

After that you can access it

YourType o = ((YourType)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionName"));

EDIT:

The Type must derive from ConfigurationSection.

Comment: Dear Verni, if you notice my config sections I do have type="System.Configuration.IgnoreSectionHandler". Please let me know if that is correct.

Comment: I noticed it. You must change the Attribute to the FQN of SagePayConfiguration + Assembly FQN.

Comment: I dint get what is Assembly FQN? Srry new to this.

Comment: Did you use an external Assembly for Sagepay or is this Type written by yourself?

The FQN of a Type looks like this:
Joe.Doe.YourType | It contains the Fullpath to the Type (Namespaces)

Comment: Also look at this: 
http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/09/27/using-sagepay-with-asp-net-mvc/ 
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well after adding the namespace I got this error "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SagePayConfiguration: Could not load file or assembly 'TheaterBalcony.Web.SagePay' or one of its dependencies. "

Comment: Did the Assembly "TheaterBalcony.Web.SagePay" exist?

How looks the type Attribute now?

Comment: That is the namespace under the class SagePayConfiguration  available . namespace TheaterBalcony.Web.SagePay
{
    public class SagePayConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
    {

Comment: Like i wrote at the top the Format must be "TheaterBalcony.Web.SagePay.SagePayConfiguration, !Assembly!"

The Assembly FQN is often not the namespace. You find the FQN of the Assembly in the ProjectFile (if you own the Code) or in the Settings Window (in VisualStudio) under "Name" or "Identity".

From the Informations it should be: 
TheaterBalcony.Web or only TheaterBalcony